# getting undefined values in java-script alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can anyone please tell me why i'm getting undefined in javascript when i run the below code.
its a simple code for getting the parent div id. All div's are closed properly but still getting undefined.

**html**

```
<div id="ricolaId_2" class="ricMo ricIndex ricBlocking ricInline"  style="width: 730px; left: 309px; top: 144px; z-index: 13000; display: block;">

    <div class="ricTitle">
        <a class="ricClose">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" title="Close">
        </span>
        </a>
        <span class="ricTitle">Manage</span>
    </div>

    <div class="ricModal ng-scope" style="height: auto;">
            <div>
                    <div>
                            <div ng-controller="Manage" class="ng-scope">
                                <div class="ricCenter">
                                    <div class="ricport">
                                        <div class="ricWr"> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <br style=""></br><br style=""></br>
                            <div align="center" class="row btn-group">
                                <button onclick="cancel(this)" class="ricSmall" type="button" id="sss" ric:loaded="true">Close</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**script**

```
function cancel(btn)
{
    try{
     ricId_1 = $(btn).parent().parent();
       alert(ricId_1.attr("id"));
    }catch(a){alert(a);}
}
```

Comment: The parent of button has no id

Comment: The `$(btn).parent().parent();` DIV has no ID, so which parent are you targeting?

Comment: yes id is there, `ricolaId_2` is the id

Comment: ricolaId_2 is not grandparent but its grandparent of grandparent

Comment: so use instead: `$(btn).closest('.ricMo');`

Comment: or you can use   `ricId_1 = $(btn).parents('div:last');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target that id you need:

```
$(btn).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

or:

```
$(btn).closest('.ricModal').parent();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Mr/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead of .parent()

```
function cancel(btn)
{
    try{
     ricId_1 = $(btn).parents('#ricolaId_2');
       alert(ricId_1.attr("id"));
    }catch(a){alert(a);}
}
```

---

**parent** method only travels a single level up the DOM tree and **parents** method travels through multiple level up the DOM tree.

Comment: i guess you mean `.parents('#ricolaId_2')` but then why using `.parents()` as ID must be unique on document context :)

Comment: If you already know the ID selector then you could just use `$('#ricolaId_2');`

Comment: so the op should use .parent().parent().parent().parent(....? Ummm, it's really bad question....

Comment: @C-link Yeah, or use .closest('.ricModal') or .parents('.ricModal:first')

Answer (score 1):

I changed a few things, and look: It's working! You should add an `id` to `ng-scope` So, http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Mr/7/

### Update

http://jsfiddle.net/8F8Mr/9/

Comment: `ng-scope` ain't angular